# restructuredtext link to other rst file menu anchor

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

With this structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── Editors.rst
└── Tool_vim.rst
```

From Editor.rst file I want to do a link to the `Tool_vim.rst` file.

I get it with:

```
Follow install from :doc:`Tool_linux_install`
```

But on Tool_linux_install.rst I have a menu with `.. contents::` and sections but I don't succeed to do a link to the vim chapter:

```
Follow install from :doc:`Tool_linux_install#vim`
```

But I get an error when compiling:

```
Tool_vim.rst:423: WARNING: unknown document: Tool_linux_install#vim
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:doc:` role can be used to link to another document, but it does not support linking to a specific location within the document.

Instead, use the [`:ref:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref) role to link to a target defined by a label. It is possible to generate labels automatically with the [`sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html) extension.

See also https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6766.